# WebPack and SoundManager2

Tags: requirejs, browserify, commonjs, soundmanager2, webpack

so I am creating my own js class using webpack to pack my client side js, and I am needing to use this "soundManager" object which is a third party library that I include on the page. SoundManager actually lives on window.soundManager... My question is how do I access this object on window.soundManager in my SoundLoader class?

```
/* global soundManager */
'use strict';

var debug = require('debug')('core:SoundLoader');

function SoundLoader() {
  this.$sm = soundManager;
}

SoundLoader.prototype.init = function(readyCallback, timeoutCallback) {
  this.$sm.setup({
    url: '/bower_components/soundmanager2/swf/soundmanager2_flash9.swf',
    onready: function() {
      if (readyCallback) {
        readyCallback();  
      }
    },
    ontimeout: function() {
      if (timeoutCallback) {
        timeoutCallback();
      }
    }
  });
};

module.exports = new SoundLoader();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `package.json` in your project, you can do this:

1. `npm i scottschiller/SoundManager2 --save`. To play it safe, you probably should point at some specific tag using the hash syntax (`#tagname`).
2. Add `var soundManager = require('SoundManager2').soundManager;` to your code. This will give you the object you were looking for.

I hope this helps.